# Volume changes by itself

Tags: sound

I have Ubuntu 13.10 on a Toshiba Satellite Pro L300 laptop and the sound slider control changes the volume all by itself, sometimes muting the sound altogether. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

try to install PulseAudio Volume Control (you may find it on Ubuntu Software Center) and control the volume from there. I had the same problem once before on 13.04 and solved it this way :)

Comment: I managed to install the PulseAudio Volume Control and so far this has seemed to have solved my problem. Thank you.